# Implement an interactive PDF View in IOS

Tags: pdf-generation

I'm trying to make a PDF View on my app that cover these functionalities:

a. Ability to fill in PDF forms and email the completed form to multiple recipients

b. Interactive PDF documents with invisible elements that appear on touch.

c. These could be “ToolTip” type text boxes or graphical elements overlaid upon images

d. Addition of bibliography to PDF’s

i. Word definitions

ii. Relationship of terms within the PDF to product features

Any ideas? Any link to open source or a paid libraries that cover any functionality will help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pdftron.com/ is a solution that I have used for integrating interactive pdf forms into an app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already solved this problem purchasing the PSPDFKit. Excellent library btw.